# Qual a diferença entre escrever os códigos de estilização no arquivo html e css?

Tags: html, css

Tem algum problema escrever os códigos dos estilização no arquivo `.html` (no `<head><style></style></head>`) ao invés de escrever no arquivo `.css`? Estou tendo um problema em meus códigos quando eu vou colocar um link em tags que necessita utilizar o atributo `href`, só funcionam desta forma de escrever: `href="C:\Users\NomedoUsuario\Desktop\Pasta\arquivo.css"`, ao invés da forma que é comumente ensinada que é: `href="arquivo.css"` (caso esteja na mesma pasta). O jeito que consegui driblar este problema é utilizar o primeiro exemplo de escrita. Isto não seria um problema se funcionasse quando colocasse em um servidor, porém não funciona. E quando coloquei o código de estilização no próprio `html` funcionou. Porém desconheço se há algum problema com essa forma de esquivar do problema com o meu código. É um problema ou um erro fazer isto? O problema é com o meu código? Ou ocorre com vocês? Alguém tem alguma indicação de como resolver?

Comment: Tem outras perguntas sobre o assunto além das mencionadas acima, sugiro dar uma pesquisada

Comment: @Bacco Ok, muito obrigado pela dica. Mas você sabe qual o problema está ocorrendo no meu código? Que eu não consigo conectar o arquivo `.css` com o `.html`. Como já disse a única solução que encontrei foi escrevendo de uma maneira (desde o "C:\") que quando coloco ele em um servidor, o código não funciona. Se resolvesse esse problema, muitos outros problemas que tenho seriam resolvidos.

Comment: Muito provavelmente você está errando o caminho do arquivo, mas só com o que tem na pergunta é impossível aferir. O melhor teste que você faz é testar digitando o arquivo no navegador pra ver se abre (no servidor). Exemplo: se o css for "nomedoservidor.com.br/estilos/arquivo.css" um href="/estilos/arquivo.css" é pra funcionar. Agora, se não configurar um servidor na sua máquina com a mesma estrutura do servidor de hospedagem fica meio dificil desenvolver.

Comment: @Bacco O problema não era esse mas seu comentário me ajudou a resolver. kskkkskskskkkkksks valeu, resolvi na cagada. Era de tempo que tava quebrando minha cabeça, mas era um problema muito besta. Mas valeu! To aqui rindo sozinho de tão simples que era...

Answer (score -4):

use a tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">` ao invés da tag `<style></style>`
e sim, tem diferença em separar arquivos e usar tudo no mesmo arquivo

Comment: Poderia também descrever quais são as diferenças e por que recomenda usar um e não outro?